# Environment variables contain wrong values in jobs

Tags: php, laravel

When I try to access an environment variable in a job (queue is database), I get an incorrect value.

I am trying to retrieve the `APP_DEBUG` variable because during development a Windows program is to be used for execution, while in the production system a Linux binary is used.
I have already restarted the queue, worked with `queue:listen`, and cleared the cache.

I assume that the `.env` is not read by the queue.

What options do I have to work around this behavior?
Or is there a solution for the problem?

Here is a sample of my code

```php
/**
 * Execute the index job.
 */
public function handle()
{
    // Some code ...
    
    if (true == env('APP_DEBUG')) {
        WindowsFileIndexer::dispatchNow();
    } else {
        LinuxFileIndexer::dispatchNow();
    }
    
    // Some more job calls ...
}
```

---

Of course I know that I could get to the operating system via other ways (PHP_OS, etc.) and thus also check it. However, it must be possible to use the environment variables in a job.

Comment: you should only be accessing `env` in your config files

Comment: define a variable in a config file for APP_DEBUG and assign .env APP_DEBUG to it.  and use config('variable') in your job. don't forget php artisan config:cache

Comment: You should do the check outside of your job, f. ex. in the controller, and only dispatch the job when your condition match.

Comment: did you use php artisan config:cache command? if so re execute the command and dry again.

Comment: Almost expected it. Thanks for your answers